# Regular Expression for Valid Active Directory Account Name

Tags: .net, regex, active-directory

Does anyone have a regex that checks if a string is a valid AD account name?

e.g. accounts can't have "@" and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739093%28WS.10%29.aspx) the UPN naming rules are based on [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html) "STANDARD FOR THE FORMAT OF ARPA INTERNET TEXT MESSAGES". It also says:

> A UPN that contains more than one @ sign is invalid.

Yet RFC 822 allows for more than one @, so I am misunderstanding the documentation or it is not actually based on that RFC. Assuming that it is in fact based on RFC 822 you can use [this regular expression](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) to validate the entire UPN (after stripping comments).

Or simpler: just try to create the user and see if it fails.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to go that route or make a 'simplified' regex (starts with [az] then numbers or letters only to make my life easy. The plan is to add as a regular expression validator (javascript) on the website, so it needs to be easy to implement and explain to the average user what the requirements are. 

Thanks!